# How to access an object created within a function from another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, object

I'm new to JavaScript and NodeJS, and I need to solve this issue quickly.

```
      connection(getSQL2)
    .then((table)=> {
        table.forEach(row=> {
            let obj = {
                countryid: row.IdPais,
                country: row.NombrePais
            };
            data.push(obj);
          });

        });

console.log(obj);
```

When I try to display the object using console.log, I get undefined, which seems pretty obvious. But what would be an easy way to get it to display the Object 'obj' that was created above?

UPDATE: Just to clarify, console.log is used here only as an example. I need to access the object from outside that function however I can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Move the console.log call inside the callback, where you defined `obj`.

Comment: I just put the console.log outside to make it clear that I need to access the object from outside. I need to get some data from that object within some other function. As if it was a global variable.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: try consoling `data`, it will be defined outside

Comment: @anwerjunaid How so?

Comment: *"I need to access the object from outside that function however I can."* And that's usually a mistake. Why do you think you need to do that? Please provide a complete example. Please read [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196).

Comment: I'm working on a project where we need to dynamically migrate an entire MsSQL db and put the contents of each table into a different MongoDB collection.

Comment: In this particular case I need to merge two SQL tables into a single Mongo collection. I know how to get fields from an object. But I can't access it because it's not a global variable.

Comment: *"I can't access it because it's not a global variable."* You don't need global variables. Put the code that needs access to the data into a function. Call the function from the callback and pass the data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things going on here.

1) You're using a promise and promises asynchronously resolve. Good rule of thumb is any code that ends with `.then(...)` is going to be a promise. What that means is that code underneath it can execute before the promise is finished and if it reads those values before the promise has finished resolving they will be read as `undefined`.

2) You use the `let` keyword to define your variable which means it will only be defined in the scope:

```
row => {
            let obj = {
                countryid: row.IdPais,
                country: row.NombrePais
            };
            data.push(obj);

            // Show the object where it is defined
            console.log(obj);
          }
```

Comment: In that case it works, but console.log is not precisely what I need.

I need to access the object as if it were a global variable from another function.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't you have access to it in your `data` array?

Comment: Only inside the arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:-

```
 async database()
{

      try {
            const table= await connection(getSQL2);
            if (table!== null)
            {
             table.forEach(row=> {
              let obj = {
                          countryid: row.IdPais,
                          country: row.NombrePais
                        }; 
             console.log('This will resolve the promise',obj);
            }
            else 
            {
             //anything needed 
            }
          } 
            catch (error) 
           {
                       // Error retrieving data
           }
}
```

`async` and `await` are the keywords used in parallel. `await` keyword will not allow the control to go down until data is fetched.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this one would be the right path.

But I'm getting this:
async database() {
      ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: I have tried this approach my issues were solved and its the correct way to resolve the promise. are you using this function in node?

Comment: I'm using Node 7.1.0 to import some SQL tables into MongoDB collections.

Comment: remove async and await keywords and then try.

Comment: you can make obj as a global variable and you can use it anywhere

Comment: function database() {
  try {
        const table = connection(getSQL2);
        if (table!== null)
        {
         table.forEach(row=> {
          let obj = {
                      countryid: row.IdPais,
                      country: row.NombrePais
                    };
         console.log('This will resolve the promise',obj);
       })
     }
               else
        {
         //anything needed
        }

    }
        catch (error)
       {
                   // Error retrieving data
       }
}

Comment: Now there's no output at all. It just runs and closes without issues.

Comment: put console in else

Comment: if its going to else then we have to use async and await keywords

Comment: TypeError: table.forEach is not a function  at database

Comment: You need to use async and await

Comment: Use babel to run async and await

Comment: how did you call the function?

Comment: I called it database();

Comment: try calling new database()

Comment: If it doesn't work then there is a problem of usage of async keyword in node es7. you have to use babel to access these keywords. Don't worry I will tell you how to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `global variable`, and assign the value to that variable inside the that function.

Then, you will be able to access the variable `obj` outside the function also.

```
var temp;//declare a global variable here.
connection(getSQL2)
.then((table)=> {
    table.forEach(row=> {
        let obj = {
            countryid: row.IdPais,
            country: row.NombrePais
        };
        data.push(obj);
        temp = obj;//assign value to global variable here
      });

    });

console.log(temp);//you can access the 'obj' using temp
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sadly not. Still undefined.

Comment: sorry, you need to do `console.log(temp)` ,  i will edit my answer.